# Do the works on sacrifices require Blessings to validate the intent?

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, beis-hamikdash, korban, thought

*Disclaimer: this is not a Halachic question and I didn't research much yet.*

There's a whole subject of having wrong thoughts when bringing a sacrifice and performing numerous actions by the owner or a Cohen. Some are so severe they invalidate the sacrifice. E.g. the beginning of Zvochim (1.1):

> All offerings that were slaughtered not for their own sake, i.e., during the slaughtering the slaughterer’s intent was to sacrifice a different offering, are fit, ... But these offerings did not satisfy the obligation of the owner, who is therefore required to bring another offering.

I thought that since all the offerings are explicit Mitzvas (AFAIK), don't they require saying a Brocho {on every action - slaughtering, accepting blood, etc) so we all be sure that the thoughts/intents were appropriate?

Comment: Many other things require intent and the bracha isn't me'akeiv, so why should it be here?

Comment: How does saying a blessing clarify what the intent was regarding when to eat the meat for example?

Comment: @DoubleAA For example if he says "אשר קדשנו בקדושתו של אהרן להקריב עולה" it is clear he's not offering Shlamim

Comment: Meaning this would only help for the one specific lishmah issue of which type korban it is.

Comment: @DoubleAA That would save 50% of troubles, given the Brocho is said at every work (by owner and Cohanim)

Comment: I don't see how it would save any trouble. Most mistaken intentions will be accompanied by mistaken blessings